# Get PHP form working with variable and htaccess

Tags: php, forms, apache, .htaccess, variables

I have a small system set up, where the form sets the variable, and the variable is then echoed from the URL in the form, so the user knows which username they are seeing information about.

http://pastie.org/6168045

At the moment, the htaccess redirect is working, as I wanted the URL to look better than displaying /?name=x

This has stopped the form working though, it now sets the variable to to this: http://dev.jaycraft.co/banned/test?name=test2

I need the form to just set it to dev.jaycraft.co/banned/test2.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you please show your .htaccess file i think i know what you mean should be like below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^banned/([^\/]*)\/?$   http://dev.jaycraft.co/banned/test.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It was: http://pastie.org/private/5nlvdsrxwdvapy7ycoqe5a I changed it to your one, but it didn't work at all then, it just reverted back to using the variable like ?name=test

Comment: is banned a folder on your web server ?